# I get black textures if i use TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP in webGL

Tags: webgl

Middle of draw code:

```js
      for(var t = 0;t < object.textures.length;t++) {
        if(object.custom.gl_texture == null) {
          world.GL.gl.activeTexture(world.GL.gl['TEXTURE' + t]);

          if (t == 1) {   var gl = world.GL.gl;
         
            var tex = gl.createTexture();
            // world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, object.textures[t]);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, tex);
            // gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            // gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
            // gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            // gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            // gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            // gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            // gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
            // gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
          
             // Get A 2D context
            /** @type {Canvas2DRenderingContext} */
            if (typeof window.TEST == 'undefined') {
              window.TEST = null;
              var T = document.createElement("canvas");
              T.id = 'blabla';
              document.body.append(T);
            
            } else {
              var T = document.getElementById("blabla");
            }

            const ctx = T.getContext("2d");
          
            ctx.canvas.width = 128;
            ctx.canvas.height = 128;
          
            const faceInfos = [
              { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, faceColor: '#F00', textColor: '#0FF', text: '+X' },
              { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, faceColor: '#FF0', textColor: '#00F', text: '-X' },
              { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, faceColor: '#0F0', textColor: '#F0F', text: '+Y' },
              { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, faceColor: '#0FF', textColor: '#F00', text: '-Y' },
              { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, faceColor: '#00F', textColor: '#FF0', text: '+Z' },
              { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, faceColor: '#F0F', textColor: '#0F0', text: 'CUBEMAP' },
            ];
            faceInfos.forEach((faceInfo) => {
              const {target, faceColor, textColor, text} = faceInfo;
              gen2DTextFace(ctx, faceColor, textColor, text);
          
              // Upload the canvas to the cubemap face.
              const level = 0;
              const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
              const format = gl.RGBA;
              const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
              gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, format, type, ctx.canvas);
            });
            gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
          
          } // 
          // App.tools.cubeMapTextures(world.GL.gl);
          else {
          // ORI
          world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, object.textures[t]);
          world.GL.gl.pixelStorei(world.GL.gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
          world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, world.GL.gl.NEAREST);
          world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, world.GL.gl.NEAREST);
          world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, world.GL.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
          world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, world.GL.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
          }

          // -- Allocate storage for the texture ORI COMMENTED
          // world.GL.gl.texStorage2D(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 1, world.GL.gl.RGB8, 512, 512);
          // world.GL.gl.texSubImage2D(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, world.GL.gl.RGB, world.GL.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
          // world.GL.gl.generateMipmap(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D);
          // ADDED HERE cubeMapSampler
          world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.uCubeMapSampler, t);
        } else {
          object.custom.gl_texture(object, t);
        }
      }
```

My shader vertex:

```c
  attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
  attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
  attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

  uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
  uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
  uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

  uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;

  uniform vec3 uLightingDirection;
  uniform vec3 uDirectionalColor;

  uniform bool uUseLighting;

  varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
  varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

  // Spot
  uniform vec3 u_lightWorldPosition;
  // uniform vec3 u_viewWorldPosition;

  // uniform mat4 u_world;
  // uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
  // uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;

  varying vec3 v_normal;

  varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
  varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

  void main(void) {

    // orient the normals and pass to the fragment shader
    // v_normal = mat3(u_worldInverseTranspose) * aVertexNormal;
    v_normal = mat3(uNMatrix) * aVertexNormal;
    // uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    // uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
    // uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

    // compute the world position of the surfoace
    vec3 surfaceWorldPosition = (uNMatrix * aVertexPosition).xyz;

    // compute the vector of the surface to the light
    // and pass it to the fragment shader
    v_surfaceToLight = u_lightWorldPosition - surfaceWorldPosition;

    // compute the vector of the surface to the view/camera
    // and pass it to the fragment shader
    v_surfaceToView = (uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0)).xyz - surfaceWorldPosition;

    gl_Position   = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

    if (!uUseLighting) {
      vLightWeighting = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
    else {
      vec3 transformedNormal          = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
      float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, uLightingDirection), 0.0);
      vLightWeighting                 = uAmbientColor + uDirectionalColor * directionalLightWeighting;
    }
  }
```

Fragment shader:

```js
    // shader for 1 textures
    precision mediump float;
    precision highp float;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

    uniform float textureSamplerAmount[1];
    int MixOperandString = 0;

    uniform sampler2D uSampler;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler1;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler2;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler3;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler4;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler5;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler6;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler7;

    // The CubeMap texture.
    uniform samplerCube uCubeMapSampler;
    varying vec3 v_normal;

    
    void main(void) {

      // normalize
      //vec3 normal = normalize(v_normal);

        vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        vec4 textureColor1 = texture2D(uSampler1, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(uSampler2, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        vec4 textureColor3 = texture2D(uSampler3, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        vec4 textureColor4 = texture2D(uSampler4, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        vec4 textureColor5 = texture2D(uSampler5, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        vec4 textureColor6 = texture2D(uSampler6, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        vec4 textureColor7 = texture2D(uSampler7, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));

        if (1 == 1) {
          // gl_FragColor      = vec4(textureColor.rgb * vLightWeighting, textureColor.a); // ori

          // gl_FragColor = textureCube(uCubeMapSampler, normal);

           gl_FragColor = vec4( smoothstep(textureColor.r, textureColor.b,textureColor.g ) , smoothstep(textureColor.r, textureColor.b,textureColor.g ) ,0 ,smoothstep(textureColor.r, textureColor.b,textureColor.g ) );
        } else if (1 == 2) {
          if ( 0 == 0) {
            gl_FragColor      = vec4( (textureColor.rgb * textureColor1.rgb) * vLightWeighting, textureColor.a);
          } else if (0 == 1) {
            gl_FragColor      = vec4( (textureColor.rgb / textureColor1.rgb) * vLightWeighting, textureColor.a);
          }
        } else if (1 == 3) {
          if (0 == 0) {
            gl_FragColor =vec4( (textureColor.rgb * textureColor1.rgb * textureColor2.rgb ) * vLightWeighting, textureColor.a);
          }
          else if (0 == 1) {
            gl_FragColor = vec4( (textureColor.rgb * textureColor1.rgb / textureColor2.rgb ) * vLightWeighting, textureColor.a);
          }
        } else if (1 == 4) {
            if (0 == 0) {
              gl_FragColor = textureColor * textureColor1 * textureColor2 * textureColor3;
            }
            else if (0 == 1) {
              gl_FragColor = textureColor / textureColor1 / textureColor2 /  textureColor3;
            }
        }

        
    }
```

Any suggestion ?

I try to push drawing but get error logs:

```
 GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Two textures of different types use the same sampler location.
```

I got faild shader compile if i add to the fragment shader

```js
    void main(void) {

      // normalize
      //vec3 normal = normalize(v_normal);
   ...
}
```

LAST UPDATE:
My uCubeMapSampler is undefined but i dont know why.

```js
 if (null !== gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uCubeMapSampler')) {
        console.log('NULL ??? ');
        shaderProgram.uCubeMapSampler = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uCubeMapSampler');
      }
```

Comment: I dont have any warnings for this code at the moment. Just black cube. I check canvas he exist with last draw call.

Comment: Looks like a forgot to add `  uniform samplerCube u_texture;` i will check now !

Comment: This is example source : https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cube-maps.html

Comment: You may have a 2D sampler looking at your cubemap, these occupy the same texture slots, as in activeTexture 1 has to be *either* a 2D texture or a cubemap you can not slot two different types of textures in the same slot.